# Check if method is accessing collection

Tags: c#, reflection, c#-5.0

#### Situation:

I am stuck in c# 5.0, I cannot upgrade to c# 6.0 in my current environment until after 2020. Meanwhile the null checks in the codebase have gotten incredibly long, and sometimes properties that are being accessed are not being checked for null before being accessed. A while ago I created a TemporaryLanguageFeatures class that contains some facsimiles of C# 6.0 behavior like nameof. I have decided to create a NullPropagation method that takes an `Expression<Func<T>>` and checks each for null before moving on to the next object in the series.

#### Problem:

When the expression includes access to a collection and the collection is empty or the index is out of range of the collection, I get the related empty collection or Index out of range error. I have access to the expression, the LambdaExpression created, and the compiled delegate/its MethodInfo. **Edit: I understand that c#6.0 does not protect against these circumstances, however in my method I am still looking to do so.**

**Without a try/catch** I need to check if the given call would produce an error for being:

A) index out of range (collection has 10 members, expression is as follows):

```
var answer = NullPropagation(() => item.Location.PhoneNumbers[500]);
```

B) The collection being empty (collection has no members, expression is as follows):

```
var answer = NullPropagation(() => item.Location.PhoneNumbers.First());
```

### Current Code:

```
var members = new List<Expression>();
```

...Fill the collection, etc.

```
var previousMethod = (MethodInfo) null;
var nullFound = members.Any(x => 
{
    if (previousMethod != null && typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(previousMethod.ReturnType)) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HIT!");
        //Todo: Detect collection empty/index out of range, return true;
    }
    previousMethod = method;
    return Expression.Lambda(x).Compile().DynamicInvoke() == null;
}
...
```

Comment: might be worth noting that Null Propogation does not protect you from `IndexOutOfRangeException`s

Comment: Huh, guess I just never ran into that when coding at home. I would still like to handle it in this case though.

Comment: Do you mean you're stuck with VS2013?

Comment: You may want to reword your question.  Null propogation does not protect against out-of-range indexes OR calling `First()` on an empty collection.

Comment: I'll adjust the wording, but the goal is the same, whether or not the c# feature does it, at this point I am trying to return null for those situations.

Comment: @PauloMorgado yes.

Comment: Well, @ChristopherCouture, your compiler only understands `C#-5.0`.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Yeah. I thought I made that quite clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive research I fixed the index access issue, however I have chosen not to correct the linq issues, and here's why:

First, it is possible to check to see if the method is any of the following linq queries that can throw an error due to an empty collection, and then check for !.Any() on the collection:

- First
- Last
- Single
- Aggregate
- Min
- Max
- Average

The problem here is that a predicate can be supplied to any of these that will limit the collection in such a way as to still return an error. Options for handling that scenario are limited. We would need to either use a try/catch to handle it (something I want to avoid) or recreate the internal logic inside the IEnumerable Linq extensions reporting a null found instead of throwing an error. Either solution is hacky, and not worth it to me. If you are reading this and seriously interested in this approach I can provide the code I put together as a Proof of Concept.

Having said that, I did correct the index access issue, here is the solution to that, inside the if block where the HIT! console writeline is in my question:

```
var collectionAccessMethod = method.Body as MethodCallExpression;
if (collectionAccessMethod != null &&
        previousMethod.ReturnType.GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.GetIndexParameters().Any())
        .Select(p => p.GetGetMethod())
        .Contains(collectionAccessMethod.Method))
{
    var index = (int) Expression.Lambda(collectionAccessMethod.Arguments[0]).Compile().DynamicInvoke();
    var collection = ((Func<IEnumerable>)Expression.Lambda(previousMethod).Compile().DynamicInvoke()).Invoke();

    if (index > collection.Cast<object>().Count() - 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```